# react-native-image-filter-kit:compileDebugRenderscript FAILED could not write file ScriptC_ColorDodgeBlend.java

Tags: react-native

I get this error when I try to build the project after installing the module react-native-image-filter-kit. I have tried but there is no way to fix it. I use windows and RN 64.0.

> Task :react-native-image-filter-kit:compileDebugRenderscript FAILED

*Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
143 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 135 up-to-date*

**Error: could not write file ScriptC_ColorDodgeBlend.java
Failed to generate class ScriptC_ColorDodgeBlend ()
RSContext::reflectToJava : failed to do reflection ((null))**

Thank you very much.